# How to insert Last Logged In time in sql and show it to next login in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using custom Login for my application. I want to insert last login date and time in database and show last login date and time when user login into application.

```
Controller Code:

public class HomeController : Controller
{

    MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities();
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(Session["LoggedUserID"]!= null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }


    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Login l)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using(MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                this.UpdateLoginLastUpdateStatus();
                var v = db.Logins.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(l.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(l.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v!= null)
                {
                    Session["LoggedUserID"] = v.UserID.ToString();
                    Session["LoggeduserName"] = v.UserName.ToString();
                    Session["LastLogin"] = v.LastWebLogin.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
        }
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","Username or Password is incorrect!!");
        }

        return View(l);
    }

    public void UpdateLoginLastUpdateStatus()
    {
        Login l = new Login();
        l.LastWebLogin = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        db.SaveChanges();
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        Session.Abandon();

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");

    }

}
```

}

Index View

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@if (Convert.ToString(Session["LoggedUserID"]) != "")
{
    <section>
        <p class="toplink">@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOff", "Home")</p>
    </section>
}
Last Logged on: @Session["LastLogin"]

You have been logged in.
```

I am able to Log In and Log Out but this Last Logged In Time is not working.

Comment: You don't seem to be actually adding the new Login to the db. I'd expect to see `db.Logins.Add(l)` or something like that

Comment: Firstly, are you storing the password as plain text? If so you should change this. Secondly you are not adding the 'new Login()' to the database context

Comment: @markpsmith : by adding db.Logins.Add(l), I am getting records in next row rather than same row. I want to edit the row. I want to store only one LastLoginTime. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line is trying to update the login `LastWebLogin` before you've even retrieved it:

```
this.UpdateLoginLastUpdateStatus();
```

You need to call this AFTER you've assigned the `Login` to the variable `v`. Additionally, the method is creating a NEW `Login` class, not using an existing one.  For that to work you'd have to pass a parameter `v` to the method. You don't even need that method really - unless you call it from multiple places and you want to avoid repeated code - it just needs to be a simple as:

```
var v = db.Logins.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(l.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(l.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
if (v!= null)
{
    // get previous login
    var prevLogin = v.LastWebLogin;
    // update with current login
    v.LastWebLogin = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    db.SaveChanges();
    Session["LoggedUserID"] = v.UserID.ToString();
    ... etc
```

Comment: Yeah it is working but there is one problem. It is showing current Login Date and Time in Index. I want previous Login Date and Time.
Thanks..

Comment: See edit: You assign the LastWebLogin to the variable `prevLogin` before it gets updated. You will need to return this to the View for display.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just made a little change.
    Session["LastLogin"] = v.LastWebLogin.ToString();
    v.LastWebLogin = DateTime.Now.ToString();

I called Session first.. Now it is working.